# Handling <pre><code> in contenteditable elements

Tags: javascript

I'm building a little content editor in one of my webpage.

This editor would allow users to insert and edit code blocks, put between `<pre><code>` tags.

Here's my issue: when I create a pre + code element, when the user press enter, the styling is forwarded to the new line.

I want either:

- The pre + code tags not to be forwarded when pressing enter
- The possibility to remove both `<pre><code>` tags — I've tried to create an "erase" button, that would launch `document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "div")`, but it only "erases" the `pre` tag, and keeps the code (so the line is still in a code tag).

Here's a fiddle that shows this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/colinfay/xpvt214o/839588/

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Do you want to keep the <pre><code> on first line?

Comment: Yes. I want either the new line (after pressing Enter) to be a new `<p>`, or the possibility to turn the `<pre><code>bla bla</code></pre>` into a single `<p></p>`